# Why is my transition vue 3 not working on "leave"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

this is the second time I have this problem which is really annoying me. I created a modal component which I use in the main component. The problem is that the modal transition wasn't working until I added the appear . I jumped for joy but the transition only works if I open the modal but when I close it's like there is no transition class to close.

this is my modal component content:

```
<template>
    <div
        v-if="show"
        class="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-60 z-20"
    >
        <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-transparent" @click="zoomOutModal"></div>
        <Transition name="slide-fade" appear>
            <div
                class="max-w-lg bg-[#151f32] w-full p-5 rounded-lg shadow-lg z-30"
                :class="{
                    'transition-all scale-105 ease-linear duration-700': zoomIn,
                }"
            >
                <h2 class="text-lg font-medium mb-3 text-center">
                    <slot>Titre du modal</slot>
                </h2>
                <slot name="content"></slot>
            </div>
        </Transition>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Buttons from '@/Components/Buttons.vue'

const show = ref(true)
const zoomIn = ref(false)

const zoomOutModal = () => {
    zoomIn.value = true
    setTimeout(() => {
        zoomIn.value = false
    }, 300)
}
</script>

<style>
.slide-fade-enter-active,
.slide-fade-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.slide-fade-enter-from {
    transform: translateY(100vh);
    opacity: 0;
}

.slide-fade-leave-to {
    transform: translateY(0vh);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
</style>
```

and this is my main content :

```
<template>
....
....
<div class="mt-6">
    <Buttons @click="showModal = true"> Ajouter Type</Buttons>
    <Modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
        Add Type
        <template v-slot:content>
            <form
                @keydown.enter="sumitAddType"
                @submit.prevent="sumitAddType"
                class="space-y-3"
            >
                <input
                    class="px-3 py-2 bg-dark-item-bg text-white border-none rounded-xl w-full placeholder-gray focus:focus:ring-blue/30"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Tapez le text le nom"
                    v-model="modalForm.name"
                />
                <div v-if="errors" class="mt-5 space-y-2">
                    <div
                        v-for="error in errors"
                        v-text="error"
                        class="text-red text-xs"
                    ></div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex gap-4">
                    <CancelButtons @click="showModal = false"
                        >Annuler</CancelButtons
                    >

                    <Buttons :disabled="modalForm.processing">
                        <div v-if="modalForm.processing">
                            <Spinner />
                        </div>
                        <div v-else>Ajouter</div>
                    </Buttons>
                </div>
            </form>
        </template>
    </Modal>
</div>
....
....
</template>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering with the modal transition might be related to the "appear" property in the "Transition" component. This property only triggers the transition when the component is first mounted, but not when it's updated later. To resolve this, you can add a "mode" property to the "Transition" component and set its value to "out-in". This will ensure that the transition works both when you open and close the modal.

```
<template>
<div
    v-if="show"
    class="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-60 z-20"
>
    <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-transparent" @click="zoomOutModal"></div>
    <Transition name="slide-fade" mode="out-in">
        <div
            class="max-w-lg bg-[#151f32] w-full p-5 rounded-lg shadow-lg z-30"
            :class="{
                'transition-all scale-105 ease-linear duration-700': zoomIn,
            }"
        >
            <h2 class="text-lg font-medium mb-3 text-center">
                <slot>Titre du modal</slot>
            </h2>
            <slot name="content"></slot>
        </div>
    </Transition>
</div>
```

Comment: No transition works now, either enter or leave.

Comment: It appears that the issue is with the "bg-[#151f32]" property in the modal component. The '-' in the color value might be causing the problem. Try using the correct syntax for specifying the background color in CSS (e.g. "bg-#151f32" or "background-color: #151f32").

Comment: it was the `appear` that made the transition `enter` work.

Comment: The same thing after adding another color bg-blue instead `bg-[#151f32]`

Comment: Anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. In my case, I put `<transition>` on the main content side and it worked.`appear` is not necessary.